# Angular NX - Import shared libraries by version

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I'm a relatively new Angular developer, looking to build a set of Angular apps that share a custom component library (and likely some other utils/interfaces).

[Nx by Nrwl](https://nx.dev/) looks like a great system for organizing these pieces, so I think I'm going to build using that.

I have one ideal spec, however, that it looks from my searches like Nx doesn't really support: The ability to version libraries, such that one app could pull in version 1.0, and the other could pull in version 2.0 of the same component library, for example.

That way, I could change, say, the Dropdown component for app 2 without affecting app 1 at all, because app 2 would just point to the new library, and app 1 to the old.

Does anybody know of a good way to do this within Nx (or good resources to figure this out; or good search terms to find those resources)? Having trouble finding guidance here, or figuring out if this is even feasible as I've thought of it.

There are obviously some hackier ways to do this:

- Have duplicative "versioned" components (Dropdown1, Dropdown2)
- Do the same for the component libraries (`import @cl2/Dropdown`)

But these solutions are non-ideal from a variety of perspectives, including need of app developers to know what version of each component is most recent, ugly component names, bloated code-base, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of NX and the monorepo approach is that everything should be running the "master" version.

By having tests for everything and running everything from the same repo you make sure to keep your whole codebase clean and up to date.

If you don't want to do it this way, you can simply have your component library as a separate repo and publish them to npm, and then pull them into your different apps using npm.

Comment: "everything should be running the "master" version" -> tightly coupled lifecycles of components -> monolith. This maybe the NX approach but is not inherently required for monorepo approach. monorepo != monolith.  I have had the same question about NX. Is there no way to have independent lifecycles?